# How to create a HTML clickable prototype from an image?

Tags: html, prototype, clickable

I have a full image (visual design) of the webpage (including menu, etc).

Normally I would use InvisionFree but school requires me to make the prototype in HTML. I have very few experience in HTML.

Do I have to start from scratch and build it in HTML? Or is there maybe a way where I can use invisible boxes that overlay my buttons (in the image) so it becomes clickable?

I tried searching myself but I couldn't find an anwser, I think my lack of knowledge is straining me. I really, really appreciate your help! Thank you so much!

Comment: You can use `<area>` to make parts of an image clickable links.

Comment: Though the question is if that is what your school actually wants. If the idea is that you learn HTML / CSS you have to start from scratch, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an image map with  and `<area>` tags, and apply it to an `<img>` with the `usemap` property.

```
<map name="mymap">
  <area shape="rect" coords="20,20,50,90" href="foo.html">
  <area shape="rect" coords="60,20,110,90" href="bar.html">
</map>
<img usemap="#mymap" src="image.png">
```

However, this is only useful for transforming an image into a barely-usable interactive prototype.

- Links can navigate to other pages, but you will need to create those other pages in HTML or from another image. (You can execute JavaScript with a `href="javascript:..."` link, but it's not clear what that JavaScript would *do*, since your page is just a giant image, rather than a document that you could manipulate.)
- Text on the pages will not be selectable, readable by text-only browsers or screen readers (e.g., for visually-impaired users), or crawable by search engines.
- The page content will not be able to wrap or resize at all if the user resizes the window or tries to resize the text. The image can only be scaled in its entirety.
- You will not be able to dynamically alter the appearance of the page, since their is no document structure. It's just an image with a few clickable parts that allow navigation to other pages.

If your school is imposing a requirement to write the demo in HTML, you should probably write it in HTML to satisfy your scholastic requirements, rather than try to use HTML markup to dress up an image. If you're only doing this to give an interactive walkthrough to an audience, it might just barely be good enough, but it's not clear what benefit you'll get that's better than simply showing your audience the mock-up images.

Answer (score 0):

You can slice the the actual images from visual design with any graphics software like Gimp (http://www.gimp.org/)

If you are not familiar with HTML/CSS you can start with a free visual/WYSIWYG HTML editor like:

KompoZer: http://kompozer.net/
or the free trial of DreamWeaver: https://creative.adobe.com/products/download/dreamweaver

In these editors you can compose a HTML page quite similar way like you edit documents in Microsoft Word. 
You can insert text, images, set colors, alignments. and it will generate the HTML markup for you. 
You can edit both the markup and via the interface and you will see the results immediately.